# After a document has been completed and signed but not submitted, how can it be invalidated/cancelled?

Tags: contract-law

I had filled out an application and signed it, but realized I was missing some additional documentation. I have since moved apartments so a lot of the info I gave is wrong. Is there something I can write on a document that means it's no longer valid? I don't own a paper shredder. Would scratching out the signature be sufficient?

To be clear, I ask this question out of curiosity. Also, does the contract exist as soon as the paper has been signed even if the other party hasn't received this, so would this be illegal?

Comment: I usually write VOID in big letters from one corner to the diagonally opposite corner.

Comment: Lacking a legal answer, shredding can be done by many means. Tear in 8 parts, dispose of in separate bags/cans/locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a line through it, rip it up and throw it out. In particular cross out your signature.

A contract is not formed until your acceptance of the offer is communicated to the other party.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an application for tenancy.  It isn't a contract but you certainly do not want to lie on it.  If you haven't given it to the apartment owner or management agent, tear it up and throw it away.  If they already have it or a copy of it, write to them by U.S.Mail or email and tell them some things have changed and ask how to proceed to get your records corrected.

If it is actually a lease document, if you are the only one who has signed it, it is not a contract.  Therefore tear it up and throw it away.

These are my personal opinions, not professional legal advice.